# Parsing float number that contains a string

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I read in a list that has 28 elements that look like this: 28.6 ft2. The list is read in not in numerical order, a bunch for different area floats.  I then click on a filter on the page and it sorts the elements from least to greatest. I have an array thats preloaded with the data designed so when I do my first expect it matches exactly. I need to take the preloaded floatarray and sort them from least to greatest. 
Here is what I have for code:

```js
var areaArray = ['5,089.8 ft2', '2,511.5 ft2', '15,076.8 ft2', '5,019.8 ft2', '471.4 ft2', '462.9 ft2', '5,149.3 ft2', '1,753.6 ft2', '6,520.5 ft2', '3,327.4 ft2', '3,192.9 ft2', '2,678.5 ft2',
  '2,793.6 ft2', '1,195.0 ft2', '148.5 ft2', '39,077.1 ft2', '5,007.7 ft2', '1,746.4 ft2', '1,247.7 ft2', '230.0 ft2', '345.8 ft2', '114.1 ft2', '229.8 ft2', '349.3 ft2', '116.3 ft2',
  '235.2 ft2', '119.5 ft2', '3,038.3 ft2'
];
//the area element list
var area = element.all(by.css("[data-bind='html: area']"));

 //this has been shortened per request
  }).then(function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://iplan-qa.meetingmatrix.com/Apps/CapacityChart/mmidemo/auto/auto');
    browser.driver.sleep(2000);
    //clicks the area filter button
    element.all(by.css("[data-bind='text: displayName, visible: displayName']")).get(3).click().click();
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    area.count().then(function(count) {
      console.log(count);
      j = 0;

      function int_arr(a, b) {
        return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b);
      }
      areaArray = areaArray.sort(int_arr);
      areaArray = areaArray.reverse();
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //scrolls down the list element by element
        browser.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", area.get(i).getWebElement());
        area.get(i).getText().then(function(text) {
          console.log(text, areaArray[j], j);
          expect(text).toEqual(areaArray[j++]);
        });
      }

    });
  });
};
```

The results look like this:

```js
5,089.8 ft2 5,089.8 ft2 0
2,511.5 ft2 2,511.5 ft2 1
15,076.8 ft2 15,076.8 ft2 2
5,019.8 ft2 5,019.8 ft2 3
471.4 ft2 471.4 ft2 4
462.9 ft2 462.9 ft2 5
5,149.3 ft2 5,149.3 ft2 6
1,753.6 ft2 1,753.6 ft2 7
6,520.5 ft2 6,520.5 ft2 8
//this is be shortened per request

39,077.1 ft2 1,247.7 ft2 0
15,076.8 ft2 1,746.4 ft2 1
6,520.5 ft2 1,753.6 ft2 2
5,149.3 ft2 1,195.0 ft2 3
5,089.8 ft2 2,511.5 ft2 4
5,019.8 ft2 2,678.5 ft2 5
5,007.7 ft2 2,793.6 ft2 6
3,327.4 ft2 3,038.3 ft2 7
3,192.9 ft2 3,327.4 ft2 8
```

Comment: What question are you asking? What is significane of the ` ft2` portion of the string? Do you have to use that string input as opposed, to say, an actual array of floats? Have you considered just going through a mapping the array of string to an array of floats and using the resuiltant array of floats for sorting using typical array sort methods?

Comment: So you want to sort the elements in `areaArray` from smallest to biggest?

Comment: @Mike it shows on screen as feet squared map cannot work because I cannot see the elements to read in that are off the screen unless I read line by line. Maps have been tried in a previous question I had asked.

Comment: @Tobias yes that is what i'm trying to do

Comment: @charlie if you look at the first paragraph it states what I'm trying to do.  I will delete what I have I was just attempting to show the entire function to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cant sort these data parsing the entire value to a number with this :

```
function int_arr(a, b) {
    return parseFloat(a) - parseFloat(b); // parseFloat('5,089.8 ft2') -> 5
}
```

You need to split the value on the space and convert the number to a float representation, removing the `,`

so `'5,089.8 ft2'` become `5089.8` when used for comparison, and not 5

```js
function int_arr(a, b) {
  var na = a.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '');
  var nb = b.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '');
  return parseFloat(na) - parseFloat(nb);
}

var areaArray = ['5,089.8 ft2', '2,511.5 ft2', '15,076.8 ft2',
 '5,019.8 ft2', '471.4 ft2', '462.9 ft2', '5,149.3 ft2', '1,753.6 ft2', 
 '6,520.5 ft2', '3,327.4 ft2', '3,192.9 ft2', '2,678.5 ft2'
];

areaArray.sort(int_arr);


document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(areaArray);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: When I do the expect it is looking for the ft2 as well, will this add ft2 back after?

Comment: this function is not updating the content of the original array. For the case of an Array of string `a` and `b` hold a copy of that string, so you can do whatever you want with these values

Comment: It sorts but in random spots.  I'm assume what I need to do is remove ft2 and then essentially add it back to the array?

Comment: what do you mean by 'in random spots' ? I edited my post to show an example

Comment: What I see from your example answered my random spots question.  Its sorting before the coma hence the random spots.

Comment: Yes, coma is not part of a number representation in javascript. So parseFloat, skip the 'second' part.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would just convert the existing array to an array of floats and work with that array of floats instead. The commas and `ft2` parts of those strings are simply display concerns and can be added when writing HTML to DOM.

```
var areaArray = ['5,089.8 ft2', '2,511.5 ft2', '15,076.8 ft2', '5,019.8 ft2', '471.4 ft2', '462.9 ft2', '5,149.3 ft2', '1,753.6 ft2', '6,520.5 ft2', '3,327.4 ft2', '3,192.9 ft2', '2,678.5 ft2',
  '2,793.6 ft2', '1,195.0 ft2', '148.5 ft2', '39,077.1 ft2', '5,007.7 ft2', '1,746.4 ft2', '1,247.7 ft2', '230.0 ft2', '345.8 ft2', '114.1 ft2', '229.8 ft2', '349.3 ft2', '116.3 ft2',
  '235.2 ft2', '119.5 ft2', '3,038.3 ft2'
];
var areaFloatArray = areaArray.map(function(item) {
    return parseFloat(item.replace(' ft2', '').replace(',', ''));
});

// then just work with areaFloatArray, which now contains float values
// you can later add back in commas and "ft2" for display
```

Comment: the dom and html are not my code I cannot change it, or I would.  Oh how I would change so much.  I am the sole automation person and they just threw me into it.

Comment: Also map functions could not work in my situation as in order for the elements to be read in I needed to scroll down line by line.  This is why I posted the entire function so could see what exactly the function was doing.